# Matrix Differentiation of $-a^T X^T y$ on $a.$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

In short; what is the correct differentiation of: 
$$S(a)=-a^TX^Ty$$ 
when differentiating: 
$$0=\frac{∂S}{∂a}= \;?$$
Long story is; I know that:
$$J(a)=\underbrace{\:\:\:a^TX^TXa\:\:\:}_u\:\underbrace{\:\:-y^TXa\:\:}_v \:\underbrace{\:\:-a^TX^Ty\:\:}_{w}+y^Ty$$
and its gradient on $a$ set to zero is:
$$0=\frac{∂J}{∂a}=\underbrace{\:\:\:a^TX^TX+(X^TXa)^T\:\:}_u \:\underbrace{\:\:\:-\:(y^TX)}_v\:\underbrace{\:\:\:-(X^Ty)^T}_w
$$

**What is the matrix differentiation rule for term $w$?**

I know the rule for term $u$. Term $v$ is like in normal analysis. Equations are taken from [Constrained Least Squares - Gavin 2015](http://people.duke.edu/~hpgavin/cee201/constrained-least-squares.pdf). I could not find that rule in the Matrix Cookbook or other university sources for Matrix Calculus or Matrix Differentiation introduction courses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$S(a)=-a^TX^Ty$$

First note the following:
$$dF(a_1,...,a_n)=\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial a_1}da_1+...+\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial a_n}da_n.$$

This is just the definition of the total derivative of a multivalued function.
We can rewrite this as a dot product:
$$dF(a_1,...,a_n)=[da_1,...,da_n][\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial a_1},...,\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial a_n}]^T.$$

We note that the term in the bracket is the gradient of $F$. Hence, $dF=da^T\cdot\nabla F^T$.

Now differentiate $S(a)$ w.r.t. $a^T$, assume $X^Ty$ to be constant and think of differentiation similar to implicit differentiation: $dS=-da^T\cdot X^Ty$.

Hence by comparision we conculde that the gradient is:
$\nabla F^T=-X^Ty$  or $\nabla F=-y^TX$.

Comment: The transposition step of $\nabla F$ is not depending on a given transposition on $a$ itself. So we get $dS=-da^T\cdot X^Ty = -y^TX$ and $dT=-da\cdot X^Ty = -y^TX$, too. Right?

Comment: But why is term $v:\:-y^TXa$ in my question not transposed to: $-(y^TX)^T$ when differentiating? Because $a$ was on its right side?

Comment: Solution in short: term $v$ uses the rule: $\frac{∂Ba}{∂a}=B^T$. Where $B$ is a substitution for $y^TX$ in this case. This results in $(y^TX)^T=X^Ty$. And term $w$ uses the rule: $\frac{∂a^TB}{∂a}=B$. With $B$ as a substitute for $X^Ty$ in this case. MrYouMath explanation is the reason why these two rules exist.

Comment: Because I can validate my last comment with the help of my lecture notes and with [Matrix Calculus (under equation F.18)](http://www.colorado.edu/engineering/CAS/courses.d/IFEM.d/IFEM.AppF.d/IFEM.AppF.pdf) I have to say that the resulting formula in Gavin 2015 is correct, but the steps towards it are not. Because I copied the steps to write my question in the first place, my question's term evolution for $v$ and $w$ is wrong, too.

Answer (score 1):

For convenience, define a new variable $$s=Xa-y$$

Then use the [Frobenius (:) Inner Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Frobenius_product) and this new variable to write the function more consisely, so that finding the differential and gradient becomes almost trivial
$$\eqalign{
  J &= s:s \cr\cr
 dJ &= 2s:ds \cr
    &= 2s:Xda \cr
    &= 2X^Ts:da \cr\cr
\frac{\partial J}{\partial a} &= 2X^Ts \cr
    &= 2X^T(Xa-y) \cr\cr
} $$
Depending on which layout convention they follow, some people will define the gradient as the transpose of this result.